# API information for Typescript's typechecker? Or: How do I call getText() when using createProgram()?

Tags: api, typescript, abstract-syntax-tree, typechecking

I'm playing around with the Typescript compiler's interface, and I found that `createSourceFile()` returns a tree with nodes where `getText()` will return the string that the node dominates. That's very useful for printing warnings and debugging.

Now I want to look around the type information, but for that I have to call `createProgram()`. Unfortunately, tree returned by getSourceFile() does not allow a call to `getText()`. The reason seems to be that the nodes don't have a parent, causing `getText()` and `getStartPos()` to crash.

So my question: is there a workaround, or even better: is there any detailed documentation on the API? The only information I found is really superficial, and the repository doesn't have any documentation on this part of the code.

Comment: really weird, I have no issues calling `program.getSourceFile('foo.ts'`).getText()` . What version of typescript do you use? 

I fully agree that there is no documentation. You probably already do this (being typescript and all), but just in case you don't: working with an editor that is aware of types + autocomplete + exploring the `d.ts` files yourself is at least somewhat helpful.

Comment: The problem isn't with the toplevel object, it's with lower objects. The source of getText() calls getSourceFile(), and the top level object is one. The lower nodes of the syntax trees however don't have a parent, and therefore can't find a source file and then the applications crashes.